# Executing task with custom and plugin's configs in sbt?

Tags: unit-testing, sbt, scoverage

I have an SBT project that has a full build definition with a custom config used for testing.

I add a plugin that comes with its own configuration, and I want to be able to execute a task using both configurations if possible.

If not possible, I would like to pull in the configuration from the plugin into my custom config.

#### The specifics

My custom config is `unit` which is used for classifying certain tests as unit tests, and I would like to add in coverage using [sbt-scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage).

My full build definition includes:

```
lazy val UnitTest = config("unit") extend(Test)
def unitTestFilter(name: String) = name endsWith "UnitSpec"

lazy val myProject = Project(id="MyProject")
         .configs( UnitTest )
         .settings( inConfig(UnitTest)(Defaults.testTasks) : _*)
         .settings(
            testOptions in UnitTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter)),
            parallelExecution in UnitTest := true
         )
```

In order to execute a unit test, I run `sbt unit:test`.

How would I A) add in `sbt-scoverage` to the `unit` configuration in the build definition, or B) include both `scoverage` and `unit` configurations in an SBT run, e.g. `sbt "unit,scoverage:test"`?

*edit* Based on the 2 answers provided, I am getting close to what I want. The problem I have now is with test filters, and applying it to the config. I have updated my original code snippet above to include the filter I used based on filename - see `testOptions` in the project section and how i used `unitTestFilter`. In order to add coverage, I have added new configs, for Coverage tests, so now have `UnitTest`, `ComponentTest`, `CoverageUnitTest` and `CoverageComponentTest`. The issue I have now is that I cannot get the test options / filename filters to propagate through to the scoverage config.

### Method 1: creating a config that extends scoverageTest

```
lazy val CoverageUnitTest = config("coverUnit") extend (scoverageTest)
def unitTestFilter(name: String) = name endsWith "UnitSpec"

lazy val myProject = Project(id="MyProject")
     .configs( UnitTest, CoverageUnitTest )
     .settings(
        testOptions in CoverageUnitTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter)),
        parallelExecution in CoverageUnitTest := true
     )
```

In the above method, the settings are not applied. If I run `coverUnit:test`, it executes both component and unit specs. I have also tried using `testOptions in scoverageTest`, which works with the filter, but the issue is that I have 2 configs in my project, namely CoverageUnitTest and CoverageComponentTest, and if I use `in scoverageTest`, then only 1 filter is applied to both tasks (i.e. coverUnit:test and coverComponent:test both execute unit tests, or component tests, based on order).

### Method 2: extending test and adding in the instrumentation

```
lazy val CoverageUnitTest = config("coverUnit") extend (Test)
def unitTestFilter(name: String) = name endsWith "UnitSpec"

lazy val myProject = Project(id="MyProject")
     .configs( UnitTest, CoverageUnitTest )
     .settings( inConfig(CoverageUnitTest)(ScoverageSbtPlugin.instrumentSettings) : _* )
     .settings(
        testOptions in CoverageUnitTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter)),
        parallelExecution in CoverageUnitTest := true
     )
```

Again, this method doesn't filter the tests with unitTestFilter.

From looking at the ScoverageSbtPlugin source, it looks like I might need to somehow look at overriding this:  `inConfig(scoverageTest)(Defaults.testSettings) ++`, is this the right approach?

*edit #2*
Here's a work-around, using Method 1, with "CoverageUnitTest" replaced with "scoverageTest":

```
lazy val dynamicTestFilter(name:String):Boolean = name endsWith scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("TEST_TYPE","UnitSpec")
```

run with `TEST_TYPE=ComponentSpec sbt coverComponent:test`

Comment: Although I responded I'm unsure about it still. What do you mean by *"add in sbt-scoverage to the unit configuration in the build definition"*? How are you going to verify whether your build configuration meet the requirement?

Comment: Basically want to run `unit:test` and have scoverage reports from that. I don't mind creating a new configuration, e.g. unitscoverage, that will allow me to run `sbt unitscoverage:test` to run my unit tests with coverage reports.

Answer (score 1):

I use sbt **0.13.5-M2**:

```
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.5-M2
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-scoverage-custom-config/}myProject 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, ScoverageSbtPlugin, scoverage.ScoverageSbtPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

Unless I'm mistaken, you're asking about applying `scoverage` settings to `unit` so executing `unit`'s `test` would be identical to executing `test:test` plus `scoverage` settings. If so, read on. Otherwise, please advise.

I think, you should have the following in the build definition (I picked `build.sbt` which was simpler for me):

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

lazy val UnitTest = config("unit") extend(Test)

lazy val myProject = project
  .in(file("."))
  .configs(UnitTest)
  .settings(
    inConfig(UnitTest)(ScoverageSbtPlugin.instrumentSettings): _*
  )
  .settings(
    parallelExecution in UnitTest := true
  )
```

As I know close to nothing about `sbt-scoverage` I can't confirm its proper configuration other than verifying the settings:

```
> unit:libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4, org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin:0.97.0:scoverage)
> test:libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4)
```

Comment: Thanks Jacek, I have given it a run, and it's almost there - adding in the `ScoverageSbtPlugin.instrumentSettings`. however, I've updated my original post to indicate another problem I'm having. I need to filter what tests to run based on filename. Method 2 above covers this approach, can you see an easy way to apply the filter?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check this but here's something you could try.

```scala
lazy val UnitTest = config("unit") extend(Test)
lazy val myProject = Project(id="MyProject").
  configs(UnitTest, scoverage, scoverageTest).
  settings(ScoverageSbtPlugin.instrumentSettings: _*).
  settings(
    parallelExecution in UnitTest := true,
    sources in scoverageTest += (sources in UnitTest).value,
    sourceDirectory in scoverageTest += (sourceDirectory in UnitTest).value,
    unmanagedResources in scoverageTest += (unmanagedResources in UnitTest),
    resourceDirectory in scoverageTest += (resourceDirectory in UnitTest),
    externalDependencyClasspath in scoverageTest := Classpaths
      .concat((externalDependencyClasspath in scoverageTest).value, (externalDependencyClasspath in UnitTest).value)
  )
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the response. I tried this approach - as per Jacek's response, it was enough to use the `instrumentSettings` in my config, without needing to do all the `scoverageTest` stuff. However, I'm battling to get a test filter working.  Is there anything overly obvious about my approach that I'm missing in order to filter tests?

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of both suggestions to come up with a working config. There's 1 ugly hack I used because I wasn't quite sure how to stop config inheritence, but here's more or less what I had (I'm only showing 1 test type - unit - here, but I actually have a number of different types. Only unit can run in parallel, component / integration test configs need parallel set to false):

```
lazy val UnitTest = config("unit") extend(Test)
lazy val CoverageUnitTest = config("coverUnit") extend (scoverageTest)
def unitTestFilter(name: String) = name endsWith "UnitSpec"
def dynamicTestFilter(name:String): Boolean = name endsWith scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("TEST_TYPE","UnitSpec")

def determineParallel:Boolean = {
  scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("TEST_TYPE","UnitSpec") match {
    case testType:String if testType == "UnitSpec => true
    case _ => false
  }
}

lazy val myProject = Project(id="MyProject")
 .configs( UnitTest, CoverageUnitTest )
 .configs( ComponentTest, CoverageComponentTest )
 .settings( inConfig(UnitTest)(Defaults.testTasks) : _*)
 .settings(
   testOptions in UnitTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter)),
   parallelExecution in UnitTest := true
 )
 .settings( inConfig(ComponentTest)(Defaults.testTasks) : _*)
 .settings(
   testOptions in ComponentTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(componentTestFilter)),
   parallelExecution in ComponentTest := false
 )
 .settings(
    testOptions in scoverageTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter)),
    parallelExecution in scoverageTest := determineParallel
 )
```

The first group of settings control unit tests (no coverage), executed with `unit:test` and the 2nd controls component tests (`component:test`). The last configuration is used for running tests with coverage enabled. The scoverageTest configuration is used for both unit and component test, but I set a system property to use a flag when running SBT to enable / disable parallel execution.

`sbt coverUnit:test` will execute unit tests using the scoverageTest configuration and enable parallel.
`$ TEST_TYPE=ComponentSpec sbt coverComponent:test` executes the component tests in the scoverageTest configuration and disables parallel execution through the determineParallel function.

Comment: Having to use an environment variable isn't elegant at all, but worked for my use case.